Advanced Composite Solar Sail (ACS3) Orbit
According to NASA the ACS3 has an altitude roughly twice that of the ISS. But according to NASAs ACS3 tracker it is visible about every 1.5 hours, same as ISS. How can it have twice the altitude but the same orbital period? I don't have a background in physics but I believe orbital period is directly proportional to distance to the 1.5 power, which would give ACS3 an orbital period of about 5 hours. I tried Googling ACS3 orbital period, orbital mechanics but I couldn't find anything that answers this specifically.

Here are distance plots for ACS3 produced using Horizons data, for the Earth centre https://i.sstatic.net/22RoBQM6.png & the Earth-Moon barycentre https://i.sstatic.net/JpM8uFo2.png , with a 3 minute timestep. Times in UTC.

Altitude above the Earth's surface is not the important number. It is altitude above the Earth's center.
So the Space Station is at an altitude of $400 + 6378$ km, and ACS$_3$ is at $1000 + 6378$ km

They do not have same orbital period. As per small body orbiting larger one, orbit period is :
$$ T=2\pi {\sqrt {\frac {a^{3}}{GM}}} ,$$
where $a$ is semi-major axis. Let's assume roughly circular motion, so they difference in orbital periods must be about
$$ 2\pi {\sqrt {\frac {(1019~km + 6371~km)^{3}}{GM}}} ~~- 2\pi {\sqrt {\frac {(423~km + 6371~km)^{3}}{GM}}} \approx 13~\text{minutes}.$$
As a second issue, difference in a non-visibility period may depend on exact geographical location from where orbital satellite(s) are monitored, because it does not reflect directly orbital period, but rather orbital shape/parameters over the region where satellite is being watched.
